# How to make CKEditor 5 insert copied text with paragraphs correctly?

Tags: text, insert, paragraph, ckeditor5

By default it works like this
https://prnt.sc/jj2wn1

I want it to save line breaks

Comment: See https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/766. There's a solution described in that ticket.

Comment: BTW, this should not be such a big issue once Soft Break plugin is implemented, which is happening right now.